# Eclipse Resource Bundle editor (table format)?

Tags: java, eclipse

I remember coding a project and when I double clicked internationalization resource bundles, a chart-like screen would pop up instead of a text editor.

I don't know what it's called and I don't know if it's a built-in struts/eclipse feature, but I do have a screenshot of what it looks like:

[image: Example of what I'm looking for]

Can anyone inform me of what this is called and how to use it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the eclipse plugin [i18ntools](http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/i18ntools)

You can install it as a plugin (`Help > Install New Software : http://eclipse.worldline.com/releases/kepler/i18ntools/1.1.0/` or use the drag&drop feature in the webpage)